# just to set it straight, understanding canonical URL

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, canonical-url

I have a question regarding canonical URLs.
My problem is that I think I understand canonical URLs but I am also not entirely sure.

I have a website that is starting to score really well in Google.
So that's fine.
However I want to create some promo sub-pages. And using canonical URLs is good. But I am afraid that if my logic has some errors I might screw up that what I've obtained and worked very hard for to obtain.

So here is my situation.

I have a website : **www.example.com**

We have several pages on this website

- *www.example.com*
- *www.example.com*/about-us.html
- *www.example.com*/how-do-we-work.html
- *www.example.com*/our-priceplan.html
- *www.example.com*/book-our-service.html
- *www.example.com*/contact-us.html

Now we would like to add some promo landingpages at **promotion.example.com**
This page should have the following pages

- *promotion.example.com*
- *promotion.example.com*/about-us.html (*duplicate from the main domain*)
- *promotion.example.com*/our-priceplan.html (* new priceplan, just for this promotion *)
- *promotion.example.com*/contact-us.html (*duplicate from the main domain *)

Since :

- about-us.html
- contact-us.html

Are duplicates from the original ones set in the main domain **example.com**, I understand that I should set for the first :

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/about-us.html" />
```

and

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/contact-us.html" />
```

for the second.

My question is.. Did I understand this correctly to avoid any penalty.
There is a lot depending on it for me. Hence my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct.  See our other questions that already cover this topic for more information.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thank you. It is not about duplicated content. The fact is that when there is an income depending on it. It is sometimes rather important to ask if you understand something correctly. You can read a think ten times. But if you are not sure you'll stay that way until someone confirms it. So thank you. :-)